# How to get system paths of windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to get all the system paths of windows. When reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/csidl?redirectedfrom=MSDN) it says to use KNOWNFOLDERID. So I followed the example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid). When try to use that example I get a compilation error.

**Test.cpp:**

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <sysinfoapi.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <combaseapi.h>
#include <WTypesbase.h>
#include <winnt.h>

int main() {
    IKnownFolderManager *pManager;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_KnownFolderManager, 
        NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&pManager)
    );
}
```

This is what I have so far. The error I get is

> error:
> invalid static_cast from type 'IKnownFolderManager*' to type
> 'IUnknown*'
> static_cast<IUnknown *> (*pp);

I am compiling from command line in windows 10 as: `g++ test.cpp`

Comment: why would adding some bin folder to environment path solve a compilation issue?

Comment: I apologize, I thought the text at the bottom of the question was how to add to the path, not get them -- happens.

Answer (score 1):

`IKnownFolderManager` requires `<Shobjidl.h>`. Without that include, the compiler doesn't know how to cast `IKnownFolderManager` to `IUnknown`.

Comment: I place the header and still get the same compilation error :/ I even tried `#include <ShObjIdl.h>`